# Not able to retrieve circles from Google+

Tags: android, google-plus

I am an amateur at using the `Google+ API` for Android. I managed to create a `GoogleApiClient` object and use the same to retrieve profile information. But am not able to use the same to retrieve the `circles` which the person has created.

I did some digging and came to know that it isn't possible through the `Google+ API` but possible only using the `Google Domains API`. Is this true? Or is there a work around for it? If its not possible using the `Google+ API`, how can go about using the `Domains API` (Since am developing a native Android application and the `Domains API` lets us request only from web apps)?

I ask this as i didn't find any concrete solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access circle information using the Google+ Domains API. This restricts operations to the domain that you have administrative access on but allows you to do more with the user information.

You can [learn about the Google+ Domains API from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/).

Comment: AFAIK, we cannot use the Google+ Domains API from Android. Am i right? Are there any tutorials to use the Google+ Domains API in an app hosted on Google App Engine? So that, i can request the server from my app.

Comment: I wouldn't say that you can't, but it might be difficult to do and could be a bad idea depending on what you're doing. 

Using Google+ Domains from a GAE app would be the same as using it from other Java (or python) app. So, if you are managing accounts on yourdomain.com, e.g. user1@yourdomain.com and user2@yourdomain.com and you want to have a task run every day from app engine that makes sure user1 and user2 have a certain settings in their circles, you could do that from GAE. 

When user1 and user2 accessed Google+ from their apps account, they would see managed changes from your GAE app.